# JQuery Variable In Selector without string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am writing a lot of code where I am using the same selectors but snippets of them for example

```
$('#menu > div.container a')
```

and

```
$('#menu span.highlight')
```

is there any method to have '#menu' in a variable and use that instead?  The issue I have with string concatenation is that it requires one to be extremey disciplined about its use as even a single missing space will mess things up.  What I would rather do is something like below:

```
var menuSelector = '#menu';
$('{menuSelector} > div.container a')
$('{menuSelector} span.highlight')
```

I have checked the documenation and such a feature does not exist.  The problem with implementing such a feature is that jQuery needs to eval within the caller's context.  Is this possible within javascript?  Secondly how might I go about implementing this feature myself?

Answer (score 6):

use node caching so you evaluate nodes faster (you start search from a cached context)

```
$menu = $('#menu');

$menu.children('div.container a')
$menu.find('span.highlight');
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
var menuSelector = '#menu';
$(menuSelector + ' > div.container a')
$(menuSelector + ' span.highlight')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid string concatenation, you achieve this using,

```
var menuSelectorObj = $('#menu');
$('div.container a',menuSelectorObj);
$('span.highlight',menuSelectorObj);
```

Comment: the second statement return all div.container at any nested level. He wants the immediate children.

Comment: then he can try with eq or firstchild also. $('div.container:eq(1) a',menuSelectorObj); OR  $('div.container:first-child  a',menuSelectorObj);

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
var menuSelector = '#menu';
$(menuSelector +  ' > div.container a')
$(menuSelector +  ' span.highlight')
```

Notice that variable is concatenated with other sting using `+` operator.

You should add `;` at the end of each line in case you are going to minify your script for faster **performance** and that is **good practice** in general:

```
var menuSelector = '#menu';
$(menuSelector +  ' > div.container a');
$(menuSelector +  ' span.highlight');
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concat string - sure you can:

```
var prefix = '#menu';

$(prefix + ' span')....
```

But if you want to query DOM elements that are childrens of `'#menu'` node - better cache this node and use it as a starting point:

```
var $menu = $('#menu') //very fast - uses native getElementById()
$menu.find('.highlight') //you do not need to specify <span>.
                         //only if you _really_ need to find <span class="highlight">

$('.highlight', $menu) //same as above - its shortcut for $elem.find()

$menu.children('.container').find('a') //not tested but maybe little faster than
                                       //child selector you use - '#menu > div.container a'
```

HTH